# Visualforce PDF not using styling how i expect it to

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF PDF page that I want to include border lines between each field. Right now the CSS i am using does not show up on the Page. Even my attempts to just have better spacing between fields has not worked.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="PDF">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Information">

<apex:outputField style="border-bottom: 5px solid black;" value="{!account.Name}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Website}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Description_Tagline__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.SS_URL__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.AV_Description__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.ShippingStreet}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Deal_Lead__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.AV_Points__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.NumberOfEmployees}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Growth_Indicators__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.AV_Founded__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Capital_Raised__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.QoQ_Growth__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Status__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Recall__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Passed_Reason__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Most_Recent_Outreach_Date__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Inbound_Email_Count__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!account.Outreach_Email_Count__c}"/>
```

[image: VF Page]

Answer (score 2):

Although this particular issue seems to be more CSS-specific (and as such not out of scope of this community), it is worth to mention that currently the Visualforce rendering technology supports only CSS 2.1 (so modern CSS guides are not that helpful if they use newer CSS).

Also, in case you don't remember, Visualforce renders with Salesforce's specific CSS by default. You should turn it off with `apex:page` attributes, such as `standardStylesheets`:

```html
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false">
    ...
</apex:page>
```